# How to reduce the vertical distance between lines in Tikz flowchart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I an new to latex and Tikz and I would appreciate your help. This is my code and I would like to remove the space shown in the picture by the red arrow.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone} \usepackage{tikz} \begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, process/.style = {draw, rounded corners, minimum width=6cm, minimum height=1cm, text width= 6cm, align=center}] 
\node (pro1) [process] {Create expensive vectors from expensive paths}; 
\node (pro2) [process, below of=pro1] {Process 1}; 
% Drawing lines 
\draw [->] (pro1) -- (pro2); 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Pleas extend your code fragmnet (for it we gavent data for used nodes styles) to complete small document. Apparently you have somewhere in preamble defined bigger (stretched)`\baselineskip`. As I see you put in node text command `\onehalfspacing ` which cause error. BTW, your code fragment contain lots of clutter ...

Comment: An example of MWE destilled from your code fragments and consider recent syntax, and works fine, is: `\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm,
process/.style = {draw, rounded corners, 
                  minimum width=6cm, minimum height=1cm, text width= 6cm, align=center}
                  ]
\node (pro1) [process] {Create expensive vectors from expensive paths};
\node (pro2) [process, below=of pro1] {Process 1};
\draw [->] (pro1) -- (pro2);
\end{tikzpicture}
`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that your document has similar structure as MWE (Minimal Working Example) below. In the first example it reproduce your problem, and in the second contain a cure for it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{setspace}  % <---
\setstretch{1.5}       % <---

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
MWE, which reproduce your problem:
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm,
process/.style = {draw, rounded corners,
                  minimum width=6cm, minimum height=1cm, text width= 6cm, align=center}
                  ]
\node (pro1) [process] {Create expensive vectors from expensive paths};
\node (pro2) [process, below=of pro1] {Process 1};
\draw [->] (pro1) -- (pro2);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

MWE with cure for your problem:
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \setstretch{1}          % <===
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm,
process/.style = {draw, rounded corners, 
                  minimum height=1cm, text width= 6cm, align=center}
                  ]
\node (pro1) [process] {Create expensive vectors from expensive paths};
\node (pro2) [process, below=of pro1] {Process 1};
\draw [->] (pro1) -- (pro2);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With comparison your code fragment an above MWE you can easy find that the placement of `\onehalfspacing`  n node content is wrong. It had to be before `tikzpicture` as is in the second example.

In the first example I remove it from node because it cause error at compilation.

For more help at your flowchart you should provide complete flowchart code in form of MWE). From provided code fragments can be concluded, that you use deprecated commands for styling and strange way of positioning: Far better is a way as is used in above MWE (with `positioning` library in its syntax).

Comment: Thank you zarko! you solved the problem!

Comment: @MariaRodriguez: It may seem strange, but on this site we generally don't offer thanks in the comments. The way to show appreciation is to [upvote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) the answers that you find helpful in addition to accepting the one you find most helpful.